Geth and lighthouse - connection problem
I have docker-compose.yml file:
services:
    geth:
        container_name: geth
        volumes:
            - /mnt/external/geth:/root/.ethereum
        ports:
            - 8551:8551
            - 8545:8545
            - 30303:30303
        networks:
            my-net:
                ipv4_address: 172.18.0.101
        image: ethereum/client-go
        command: --syncmode=full --gcmode archive --authrpc.jwtsecret
            /root/.ethereum/jwt.hex
    lighthouse:
        ports:
            - 9000:9000/tcp
            - 9000:9000/udp
            - 9001:9001/udp
            - 5052:5052
        networks:
            my-net:
                ipv4_address: 172.18.0.202
        container_name: lighthouse
        volumes:
            - /mnt/external/lighthouse:/root/.lighthouse
        image: sigp/lighthouse
        command: lighthouse --network mainnet beacon --http --http-address 0.0.0.0
            --checkpoint-sync-url https://checkpointz.pietjepuk.net/ --eth1
            --execution-jwt /root/.lighthouse/jwt.hex --execution-endpoint
            http://127.0.0.1:8551/

networks:
    my-net:
        name: my-net
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            config:
              - subnet: "172.18.0.0/16"

and I am getting error from lighthouse:
Nov 09 00:29:59.019 ERRO Error during execution engine upcheck   error: HttpClient(url: http://127.0.0.1:8551/, kind: request, detail: error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 111)), service: exec

Seems like lighthouse cannot connect to geth. How to fix that?
